# Use Jenkins-Plugin in Jenkins-Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to incorporate the [ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) into a Jenkins-Pipeline. Currently, I'm using the step-method to invoke the ClearCase-plugin:

```
step([
    $class: 'hudson.plugins.clearcase.ClearCaseUcmSCM',
    stream: "MY_STREAM",
    loadrules: "load \\SOMETHING\\int load \\OTHER load \\RESOURCES",
    [...]
    changeset: "BRANCH",
    viewStorage: null
])
```

As far as I understood the plugin-system the instantiation is done using the constructor annotated with @DataBoundConstructor:

```
src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ClearCaseUcmSCM.java:

@DataBoundConstructor
public ClearCaseUcmSCM(String stream, String loadrules, String viewTag, boolean usedynamicview, String viewdrive, String mkviewoptionalparam,
        boolean filterOutDestroySubBranchEvent, boolean useUpdate, boolean rmviewonrename, String excludedRegions, String multiSitePollBuffer,
        String overrideBranchName, boolean createDynView, boolean freezeCode, boolean recreateView, boolean allocateViewName, String viewPath,
        boolean useManualLoadRules, ChangeSetLevel changeset, ViewStorage viewStorage, boolean buildFoundationBaseline) {
```

I copied most of the parameters (boolean, String, integers) from a similar project's config.xml-file. Unfortunately, I get an Exception: 
  "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch"

I guess it's because I can't create "ChangeSetLevel" and "ViewStorage" (the latter is not even in the config.xml).

So my question is how to invoke the plugin properly.

---

Additionally, I'd like to know how to pass "loadrules" properly as there seems to be newlines in the config.xml:

```
"load \\SOMETHING\\int[NEWLINE] load \\OTHER[NEWLINE] load \\RESOURCES"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Pipeline Syntax of your job and use Snippet Generator to construct your `step`. It can be found at `http://[jenkins-url]/pipeline-syntax`.
More info in the [Jenkins pipeline docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator).

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an entry in the Snippet Generator for the ClearCase-Plugin